# Can't install SQL Server after Visual Studio Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to re-install SQL Server Express from http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/.

Visual Studio Web was installed previously, so I removed the SQL Server under add programs before installation, since I didn't get a server administration tool with the bundle.

Now, Microsoft (hello, haven't meet in five years), presents an interface to me (SQL Server Installation Center), with endless popups, progress bars, and eula checkboxes, but nothing more than "Setup Support Files" are being installed.

Are they pulling my leg? (Delicate humor if so, the loop is quite annoying, and finally ends with a crash).

Any way to fix this or should I fallback to a FOSS-db?

regards,
//t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).  Best case scenario is it will help you get what you need installed (inc. SQL EXPRESS) on top of what you have.  Worst case it'll make the process a lot easier if you decide to do a clean build.

Comment: I was able to launch it, select sql-server express, set sa-password, then fail again. Redoing it from scratch now... Thanks anyhow!